# Is platform.js considered "Polymer"?

Tags: polymer

I've been studying web components, and have gotten Google charts working.
It requires

```
bower_components/platform/platform.js
bower_components/google-chart/google-chart.html
```

But I don't see the word Polymer being mentioned.

Is platform.js considered Polymer, or do I need to include some sort of Polymer for cross browser compatibility?

Comment: Platform.js is not polymer they are polyfils to fill browers gap which do not support web components natively , did you see google-chart source code it must be internally calling polymer.html which has reference to polymer.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajay's comment is correct: `platform.js` is not strictly a part of Polymer.

`platform.js` contains the polyfills to provide Web Components technology on non-supporting browsers.

> But I don't see the word Polymer being mentioned.

It's part of the appeal of Web Components that you do not need to know the underlying technology to use a custom element. Polymer elements import `polymer.html` internally to provide the necessary code, but you never need to be aware of this if you don't care.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `platform.js` can be used for other Web Components systems, like [x-tags](http://www.x-tags.org/).

Comment: Good answer.  platform.js has since been renamed to webcomponents.js to help avoid this type of confusion.

Answer (score 10):

Platform.js has been renamed to Webcomponents.js
Google is trying to separate webcomponent polyfills with Google's polymer elements. (core-*, paper elements, etc.)

Source:
https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2014/10/16/platform-becomes-webcomponents/